# JSON and escaping characters

Tags: json, unicode

I have a string which gets serialized to JSON in Javascript, and then deserialized to Java.

It looks like if the string contains a degree symbol, then I get a problem.

I could use some help in figuring out who to blame:

- is it the Spidermonkey 1.8 implementation? (this has a JSON implementation built-in)
- is it [Google gson](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)?
- is it me for not doing something properly?

Here's what happens in JSDB:

```
js>s='15\u00f8C'
15°C
js>JSON.stringify(s)
"15°C"
```

I would have expected `"15\u00f8C'` which leads me to believe that Spidermonkey's JSON implementation isn't doing the right thing... except that the [JSON homepage's syntax description](http://json.org/) (is that the spec?) says that a char can be

> any-Unicode-character-
>       except-"-or-\-or-
>       control-character"

so maybe it passes the string along as-is without encoding it as \u00f8... in which case I would think the problem is with the gson library.

Can anyone help?

I suppose my workaround is to use either a different JSON library, or manually escape strings myself after calling `JSON.stringify()` -- but if this is a bug then I'd like to file a bug report.

Comment: grrr... and never mind the fact that my Windows PC decided to use character sets that map degree symbol to \u00f8 instead of \u00b0!

Answer (score 88, accepted):

This is not a bug in either implementation. There is no requirement to escape U+00B0. To quote the [RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt):

> **2.5.  Strings**
>
> The representation of strings is
>   similar to conventions used in the C
>   family of programming languages.  A
>   string begins and ends with quotation
>   marks.  All Unicode characters may be
>   placed within the quotation marks
>   except for the characters that must be
>   escaped: quotation mark, reverse
>   solidus, and the control characters
>   (U+0000 through U+001F).
>
> Any character *may* be escaped.

Escaping everything inflates the size of the data (all code points can be represented in four or fewer bytes in all Unicode transformation formats; whereas encoding them all makes them six or twelve bytes).

It is more likely that you have a text transcoding bug somewhere in your code and escaping everything in the ASCII subset masks the problem. It is a requirement of the JSON spec that all data use a Unicode encoding.

Comment: @user: There's nothing remotely lazy in supporting characters that aren't in the English basic alphabet. Welcome to 2015, where we don't use ASCII anymore.

Answer (score 79):

hmm, well here's a workaround anyway:

```
function JSON_stringify(s, emit_unicode)
{
   var json = JSON.stringify(s);
   return emit_unicode ? json : json.replace(/[\u007f-\uffff]/g,
      function(c) { 
        return '\\u'+('0000'+c.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)).slice(-4);
      }
   );
}
```

test case:

```
js>s='15\u00f8C 3\u0111';
15°C 3◄
js>JSON_stringify(s, true)
"15°C 3◄"
js>JSON_stringify(s, false)
"15\u00f8C 3\u0111"
```

Comment: Pinging an old answer here, but it appears this would fail for characters outside the BMP.

Comment: Is fixing that as simple as just increasing the upper-end of the boundary to "\u10ffff" though?

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Unicode/Character_reference

Comment: @owacoder it incidentally works outside BMP because the regex matching is not Unicode-aware pre-ES2015, and breaks on ES2015-compliant engine if you change `/g` to `/gu`. Thankfully, the default `/g` behavior is unchanged for backward compatibility reasons, and so it still works in 2023

Answer (score 9):

This is SUPER late and probably not relevant anymore, but if anyone stumbles upon this answer, I believe I know the cause.

So the JSON encoded string is perfectly valid with the degree symbol in it, as the other answer mentions. The problem is most likely in the character encoding that you are reading/writing with. Depending on how you are using Gson, you are probably passing it a `java.io.Reader` instance. Any time you are creating a `Reader` from an `InputStream`, you **need** to specify the character encoding, or `java.nio.charset.Charset` instance (it's usually best to use `java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8`). If you don't specify a `Charset`, Java will use your platform default encoding, which on Windows is usually [CP-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252).