# Unrecognized character while parsing JSON

Tags: java, json, parsing, unicode, jackson

I have a String like this which is coming in a JSON `processing data call\\U007fabc computers` when I try to parse it jackson throwsn an exception like this:

```
org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Unrecognized character escape 'U' (code 85)
 at [Source: java.io.StringReader@1b43c429; line: 1, column: 361]
        at org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParser._constructError(JsonParser.java:1292)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.JsonParserMinimalBase._reportError(JsonParserMinimalBase.java:385)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.JsonParserMinimalBase._handleUnrecognizedCharacterEscape(JsonParserMinimalBase.java:360)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.ReaderBasedParser._decodeEscaped(ReaderBasedParser.java:1064)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.ReaderBasedParser._finishString2(ReaderBasedParser.java:785)
        at org.codehaus.jackson.impl.ReaderBasedParser._finishString(ReaderBasedParser.java:762)
```

I think the problem is happening because of `\\U007f`. It definitely means something in UTF-8. Any idea how we can avoid this issue? Does `JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_BACKSLASH_ESCAPING_ANY_CHARACTER` will help anything here?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself.  (You need to show us the actual JSON text, not simply a few characters from it.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your JSON data is malformed.

JSON uses the `\u` escape sequence to encode a UTF-16 codeunit.

In this case, your JSON data is trying to escape Unicode codepoint `U+007F DELETE` (which is an ASCII control character that is not *required* by the [JSON spec](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf) to be escaped, but is *allowed* to be escaped), but is using the `\U` escape sequence to do so.  The [JSON spec](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-404.pdf) explicitly states that `\u` MUST be used:

> A string is a sequence of Unicode code points wrapped with quotation marks (U+0022). All characters may be placed within the quotation marks **except for the characters that must be escaped**: quotation mark (U+0022), reverse solidus (U+005C), and the **control characters U+0000 to U+001F**. There are two-character escape sequence representations of some characters.
>
> ...
>
> **Any code point may be represented as a hexadecimal number**. The meaning of such a number is determined by ISO/IEC 10646. If the code point is in the Basic Multilingual Plane (U+0000 through U+FFFF), then it may be represented as a six-character sequence: a reverse solidus, **followed by the lowercase letter u**, followed by four hexadecimal digits that encode the code point.
>
> ...
>
> To escape a code point that is not in the Basic Multilingual Plane, the character is represented as a twelve-character sequence, encoding the UTF-16 surrogate pair.

Although not explicitly stated in that last paragraph, the twelve-character sequence for a UTF-16 surrogate pair consists of two six-character sequences that must follow the same escape format as characters in the BMP.  This is enforced by the character encoding diagram:

[image: diagram]
<sub>(source: [json.org](http://www.json.org/string.gif))</sub>

There is no `\U` escape sequence defined.  That is what the parser error message is complaining about:

> Unrecognized character escape 'U'

Comment: So basically it means we are getting data like this  `\\U007` somehow which is not valid? Or after encoding it is becoming like this?

Comment: Presumably your JSON does not actually contain `\\U` but just `\U` or else it would not be processed as an escape sequence to begin with. Are you are looking at the JSON data in a debugger or something?  But yes, `\U` (uppercase U) is not valid, it must be `\u` (lowercase u) instead: `\u007f` (the `f` is part of the encoded sequence)

Answer (score 1):

Unicode Character `U+007F DELETE` is probably what you are facing.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12271569/1304575) states that it shouldnt have been encoded.

However to circumvent, you can refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/123340/1304575) on how to strip them off.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. So you are saying this shouldn't have been encoded at all right? If it wouldn't have been encoded, then how will it look like then?