# is there a reason why a notification script would suddenly start throwing out Slack API Code 400: Invalid Blocks?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, slack-api, http-status-code-400, slack-block-kit

I've had this script working for over 3 months with no issues, however, last week it started throwing out this:

```
Error   
Exception: Request failed for https://hooks.slack.com returned code 400. Truncated server response: invalid_blocks (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response)
```

Here's the relevant part of the script i think.

```
  for (let i = 0; i in vistasVencimiento; i++){
    if (vistasVencimiento[i][0] instanceof Date == true){
      let differenceInMs = dateToday - vistasVencimiento[i][0];
      let differenceInDaysRaw = differenceInMs / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);

      if(differenceInDaysRaw >= 0 && statusColumn[i] !== "Pendiente_de_despacho"){
        //agregar a array de vencidos
        result.push(sumariantesVistas[i], causasCaratulas[i], '\n');
      }
    }
  };
  console.log(result);
  if (result === undefined || result.length === 0 ){
    let payload ={
    "blocks": [
        {
            "type": "section",
            "text": {
                "type": "mrkdwn",
                "text": ":bell: *Cuales Vistas estan vencidas?* :bell:"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "section",
            "text": {
                "type": "mrkdwn",
                "text":"Aparentemente, ninguna"
            }
        },
    ]
  }
      let headers = {
      'Content-type': 'application/json'
    };
    let options = {
      headers : headers,
      method: 'POST',
      payload: JSON.stringify(payload)
    };
  UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);

  }else{
    let result_string = result.join('\n');
    let payload ={
    "blocks": [
        {
            "type": "section",
            "text": {
                "type": "mrkdwn",
                "text": ":bell: *Cuales Vistas estan vencidas?* :bell:"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "section",
            "text": {
                "type": "mrkdwn",
                "text":"Estas: "
            }
        },
        { 
            "type": "section",
            "text": {
                "type": "mrkdwn",
                "text": result_string
            }
        },      
    ]
  }
      let headers = {
      'Content-type': 'application/json'
    };
    let options = {
      muteHttpExceptions: false,
      headers : headers,
      method: 'POST',
      payload: JSON.stringify(payload)
    };
  UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);

  };
```

Now, I know its related to `"text": result_string` because ive tried replacing that with something like "text": "test" and it works, but the whole point of the notifications is to send that formatted string to a slack workplace channel, and thats where ive basically no clue on why it would start failing out of a sudden like that

edit:
Theres something genuinely very weird going on here, first of all going causasCaratulas[i].replace(/"/g, "'") doesnt fix anything, second, causasCaratulas has two columns inside, if i load only one column (doesnt matter which) the script works, ive even tried splitting the array into two sorta-lists, in that case, it still throws out **the** error.
So the error happens somewhere between trying to send out those two columns to the slack api at the same time? im clueless as to whats happening here

edit 2:
the data is structured something like this. the problem seems to be that whenever i try sending both Case Number and Case Name at the same time i get an error, however, this seems to be dependant on some kind of mystery symbol idk how to identify, if it even is a symbol.[image]

Comment: so, what is the result of `console.log(result);` when the error occurs?

Comment: @Bravo, a bunch of names and court id numbers basically, that part is working fine, in fact i just checked, it used to work fine until about 10 days ago, and nothing changed afaik

Comment: so, in short, it's an Array of strings?

Comment: @Bravo, yes, but before trying to send that result i do let result_string = result.join('\n'); to send it as a string, cause afaik you cant send arrays thru blocks

Comment: I just wonder if the `\n` is suddenly an issue on the server - to test, join with something else - or instead of `"text": "test"` send `"text": "test\ntest"` and see if the issue happens

Comment: I've now tried both doing `"text" : "test\ntest"` and doing a sort of test string thing `let test_string = "test"`, and both work, so uhhhh, hm, i still got no clue

Comment: Can you explain what the contents for `sumariantesVistas[i], causasCaratulas[i]`  are?

Comment: @Emel, yes, theyre both strings.

Comment: Can you check, via `console.log` that the contents of the result var are the expected ones? If everything is working until now, something should have changed. Also, where do these values come from? A fetched resource or data from sheet?

Comment: @Emel yes. the contents of `result` are expected, the values come from arrays im loading up with data from a sheet. and no, thats the issue, nothing has changed, thats whats confusing me rn

Comment: @IlanFritzler That's odd. Can you share a sanitized copy of the sheet? Also, you can  try making a copy of the Spreadsheet and check if the error  persists? Is it a bounded script or a standalone?

Comment: I just tried to run the script on a copy of the sheet (where i replaced all the case numbers with a simple "censored" and it works fine???? SIGH what the heck

Comment: @IlanFritzler Check the answer posted. Consider accepting or up-voting  it.

Comment: @Emel, im not sure if its that either since i just tried it on an identical copy and it failed. so it must be something else.

Comment: @IlanFritzler What do you mean with `replaced all the case numbers with a simple "censored"` ?

Comment: @Emel, sorry, im panicking a bit and i misspoke, in the sheets doc theres a column called "Caratula" in that column there are the names of the cases currently being worked on by the court, when i replaced all the values there with "censored" it worked, so im guessing something must've happened or some symbol was used and now thats causing the error.

Comment: @IlanFritzler Can you share a sample of the `Caratula` values? What kind of characters are included ? If you don't share a copy of your sanitized copy of the sheets it is very difficult for the community to provide help.

Comment: @Emel, here's a midly sanitized sheet, https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11bZ-fHy3cXbHY4IDgQmiRoBTJyq4s40p0ZDznrAvxxo/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Seems there is some sensible data in your sheet, be careful on what you share.

Comment: @Emel, i know, im gonna delete the file as soon as ive sorted the issue, but for now i kinda need that data there because whats causing the error seems to be in there especifically.

Comment: `JSON.stringify` should clean all Unicode characters except for `"` and `/`, so try to replace the ones present in the Caratulas. Try this, `causasCaratulas[i].replace(/"/g, "'")` I strongly recommend you to sanitize before sharing.

Comment: @Emel, ive deleted the gdocs file already so thanks for the warning and also for the (Yet to be tested) solution

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245794/discussion-between-ilan-fritzler-and-emel).

Comment: @IlanFritzler Also clean the `\` chars if there's any. I made a mistake in my previous comment, you can check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12271547/shouldnt-json-stringify-escape-unicode-characters) for full explanation.

Comment: Side note: Use [tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to show your data structure. If you share spreadsheets, do note that [your email address can be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/).

Comment: @TheMaster, thank you, ill see what i can do

Comment: @TheMaster tried doing the markdown table thing but even tho it showed properly when previewing it didnt rly work when actually editing, so i added an image of it as a sort of workaround

Comment: You just need to add a empty line  before the top of the table.

Comment: Have you managed to solve the issue?

Comment: @Emel, i havent, i managed to sort of avoid it by sending two columns instead of three but it still throws out an error about 50% of the time, its really weird and im not sure anymore if its a me error or something wrong with the slack api.

Comment: Try to update and reduce your question to refer to what the actual problem is. Or formulate a new one

Comment: @Emel thats not an entirely bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps your text data contains `&<>`? Try this:

```
    let result_string = result
      .join('\n')
      .replace(/&/g, '&amp;')
      .replace(/</g, '&lt;')
      .replace(/>/g, '&gt;');
```

See [Escaping text](https://api.slack.com/reference/surfaces/formatting#escaping) at Slack API reference.

You should also search your data for markdown symbols that could throw a spanner in the works.

Comment: just tried this, does not seem to work either, im guessing theres something wrong with the array per se? but ive 2 other scripts that do basically the same thing and ive gotten 0 errors with those.

Comment: You could well have other issues with your markdown syntax. It is unlikely that you will get a solution here unless you share sample data, or at minimum the output of `console.log(result_string)`, that reproduces the issue.

Comment: it must be something like this, im checking the sheet data, yet i cannot figure out what symbol is causing the issue