# Degree '°' character not displaying in php json_encode function, how to display this?

Tags: php, json

I pass php array like

```
[sit_latitude] => 20° 23.298' N
```

inside json_encode(); and output is like,

```
  {"sit_latitude":null}
```

it's display null, how to resolve this?

my code snippet

```
...
$stmt->bindParam("id", $_GET[id]);
$stmt->execute();
$employee = $stmt->fetchObject();
$dbh = null;
echo '{"item":'. json_encode($employee) .'}';
```

Comment: Please post the real php code and your locale configuration.

Comment: My guess is that your file is not saved as UTF-8.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

what i tried and succeed was bit strange but worked , so let me share it with you.

```
$latitude = json_encode(utf8_encode($emplyoee['sit_latitude']));
$longitude = json_encode(utf8_encode($employee['sit_longitude']));

   $emplyoee['sit_latitude'] = $latitude;
    $emplyoee['sit_longitude'] = $longitude;
```

and now pass like

```
echo '{"item":'. json_encode($employee) .'}';
```

this will solve your problem

Answer (score 5):

[json_encode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) assumes that strings in its input are valid [UTF-8](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) (keep in mind that PHP strings are sequences of bytes, not sequences of Unicode code points). If your text editor is not set to use that encoding (and you haven't manually generated the UTF-8 using hex escape codes such as `\xc2\xb0` in a double-quoted string), the string will be encoded as `null` (because it is not valid UTF-8).

Other common charsets such as [Windows-1252](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) are also a superset of ASCII, so this is only a problem if there are any non-ASCII characters (U+00B0 DEGREE SIGN included).

Even if the string is valid UTF-8, by default, json_encode will output `\u00b0` instead of the actual degree sign. This is not a problem for programmatic decoding using PHP [json_decode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) or JavaScript [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse), which understand JSON hex escape sequences.

(In PHP 5.4, there is a `JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE` flag to prevent this escaping. However, many web servers still have PHP 5.3 or older, and the flag unescapes even the problematic characters U+2028 LINE SEPARATOR and U+2029 PARAGRAPH SEPARATOR. It is possible to simulate the flag in two lines of code, although as I explained above, you don't have to anyway.)

Answer (score 4):

[JSON and escaping characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4901133/json-and-escaping-characters) - this post may help you.

Just pass degree as `\u00f8C` and then decode it with js.

Answer (score -4):

You could try htmlspecialchars() function  http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

Comment: Please note that JSON is not HTML.

Comment: htmlspecialchars doesn't escape the degree sign at all, so it won't help. In fact, on PHP 5.4 installations, the function may even return an empty string for the asker (because of invalid UTF-8).