# Decode JSON string in Mojolicious that was encoded with JSON.stringify

Tags: javascript, json, perl, utf-8, mojolicious

I am trying to send javascript variable as JSON string to Mojolicious and I am having problems with decoding it on perl side. My page uses utf-8 encoding.

The json string (value of `$self->param('routes_jsonstr')`) seems to have correct value but `Mojo::JSON` can't decode it. The code is working well when there are no utf-8 characters. What am I doing wrong?

Javascript code:

```
        var routes = [ {
            addr1: 'Škofja Loka', // string with utf-8 character
            addr2: 'Kranj'
        }];
        var routes_jsonstr = JSON.stringify(routes);
        $.get(url.on_route_change,
            {
                routes_jsonstr: routes_jsonstr
            }
        );
```

Perl code:

```
sub on_route_change {
    my $self = shift;

    my $routes=j( $self->param('routes_jsonstr') );
    warn $self->param('routes_jsonstr');
    warn Dumper $routes;
}
```

Server output

```
Wide character in warn at /opt/mojo/routes/script/../lib/Routes/Homepage.pm line 76. 
[{"addr1":"Škofja Loka","addr2":"Kranj"}] at /opt/mojo/routes/script/../lib/Routes/Homepage.pm line 76. 
$VAR1 = undef;
```

Last line above shows that decoding of json string didn't work. When there are no utf-8 characters to decode on perl side everything works fine and `$routes` contain expected data.

Comment: You'd need to apply the `:utf8` stream discipline to wherever Mojo::JSON is getting its param values from, but from what I see in the Mojo::JSON documentation on CPAN, it should apparently already be doing that. If you can, try installing and using the JSON module from CPAN; I've had good results using that to decode utf8-encoded JSON data.

Comment: `$routes=JSON->new->utf8(0)->decode( $self->param('routes_jsonstr') );`

Comment: Can you do that with Mojo::JSON, or only with JSON.pm?

Comment: Sorry for my failure with the previous comment: I got it to work with JSON.pm and disabled utf8. This seems to work:  `$routes=JSON->new->utf8(0)->decode( $self->param('routes_jsonstr') );` . With enabled utf8(1) it dies with error `Wide character in subroutine entry at /opt/mojo...` . I also replaced $.get() with $.post() in javascript but I think this has no effect.

Comment: Oh awesome! Mind if I convert the comment to an answer?

Comment: Yes, please convert it. And thanks for help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mojolicious style solution can be found here: 
http://showmetheco.de/articles/2010/10/how-to-avoid-unicode-pitfalls-in-mojolicious.html

In Javascript I only changed $.get() to $.post().
Updated and working Perl code now looks like this:

```
use Mojo::ByteStream 'b';
sub on_route_change {
    my $self = shift;    
    my $routes=j( b( $self->param('routes_jsonstr') )->encode('UTF-8') );
}
```

Tested with many different utf8 strings.

Answer (score 1):

Wide character warnings happen when you print. This is not due to how you decode your unicode but your STDOUT encoding. Try `use utf8::all` available from CPAN which will set all your IO handles to utf8. Avoiding decoding probably isn't fixing the problem, but rather making it worse. The only reason it appears to work is your terminal is fixing things up for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can take away at least some of the pain by escaping the problematic characters; see https://stackoverflow.com/a/4901205/17389.

Comment: Thank you. When using custom JSON_stringify function as suggested in the link you provided, I can enable utf8 decoding on perl side: `$routes=JSON->new->utf8(1)->decode( $self->param('routes_jsonstr') );`