# Write ObjectNode to JSON String with UTF-8 Characters to Escaped ASCII

Tags: java, json, unicode, utf-8, jackson

I would like to write the contents of Jackson's `ObjectNode` to a string with the UTF-8 characters written as ASCII (Unicode escaped).

Here is a sample method:

```java
private String writeUnicodeString() {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    ObjectNode node = mapper.getNodeFactory().objectNode();
    node.put("field1", "Maël Hörz");
    return node.toString();
}
```

By default, this outputs:

```json
{"field1":"Maël Hörz"}
```

What I would like it to output is:

```json
{"field1":"Ma\u00EBl H\u00F6rz"}
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Via something like http://stackoverflow.com/a/4901205/3080094 ?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You should enable the `JsonGenerator` feature which controls the escaping of the non-ASCII characters. Here is an example:

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.getFactory().configure(JsonGenerator.Feature.ESCAPE_NON_ASCII, true);
ObjectNode node = mapper.getNodeFactory().objectNode();
node.put("field1", "Maël Hörz");
System.out.println(mapper.writeValueAsString(node));
```

The output is:

```json
{"field1":"Ma\u00EBl H\u00F6rz"}
```

Comment: On java play 2.3, the import are : com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode     com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper

Comment: in which package/version is JsonGenerator from?

Comment: JsonGenerator.Feature.ESCAPE_NON_ASCII Since 2.10 use JsonWriteFeature.ESCAPE_NON_ASCII instead
read more - https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.10/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonGenerator.Feature.html

Answer (score 11):

`JsonGenerator` is deprecated use `JsonWriteFeature` instead of it.

```java
mapper.getFactory().configure(JsonWriteFeature.ESCAPE_NON_ASCII.mappedFeature(), true);
```

Comment: I think you wanted to say that `JsonGenerator.ESCAPE_NON_ASCII` is deprecated. I don't see that `JsonGenerator` itself is deprecated, is it?

Comment: in which package/version is JsonWriteFeature from?

Comment: @AjayTakur, it is in the `com.fasterxml.jackson.core.json` package.