# NSDictionary Posting Unicode Characters

Tags: ios, objective-c, unicode, nsdictionary

I need to post Unicode characters to a database. The database I am using receives a NSDictionary and stores that as a JSONObject.

The dictionary is created like:

```
NSMutableDictionary *messageDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init ];

[messageDictionary setObject:@"message" forKey:@"type"];
[messageDictionary setObject:@"È ê ü à ã" forKey:@"message"];
```

The database then stores the result as:

```
{
    type = message;
    message = \"\\U00c8 \\U00ea \\U00fc \\U00e0 \\U00e3\";
}
```

if I post just the string outside of the dictionary the database stores:

```
{
    message = Ãˆ Ãª Ã¼ Ã  Ã£
}
```

How do I prevent the NSDictionary from editing these characters and storing them the same way they are entered into a Text View. The same goes for when entering Emoji's into a Text View and sending that. The response I need stored is:

```
{
    type = messages;
    message = "È ê ü à ã";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Conversion from `@"È ê ü à ã"` to `@"\U00c8 \U00ea \U00fc \U00e0 \U00e3"` is **not** something `NSDictionary` does, so I would assume this is done by the JSON encoder.

I would expect the JSON decoder to put them back to their original form, so the answer is to use a good JSON decoder (by "good" I mean "one that works").

To quote an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4901133/json-and-escaping-characters):

**2.5. Strings**

The representation of strings is similar to conventions used in the C family of programming languages. A string begins and ends with quotation marks. All Unicode characters may be placed within the quotation marks except for the characters that must be escaped: quotation mark, reverse solidus, and the control characters (U+0000 through U+001F).

**Any character may be escaped.**

Comment: I had misquoted the NSLog with the Server Response, sorry. Updated my question with the stored message with escaped strings. So this would be a server side problem that is changing the characters and is irrelevant of the NSDictionary? If I post just the textview text instead of dictionary I store `Ãˆ Ãª Ã¼ Ã  Ã£`

Comment: @GeorgeGrover Yes.  The server side JSON decoder is broken.