# Handling JSON with symbols

Tags: java, json, gson

I have been having issue with the following scenario:

We have a JSON which contains the degree symbol (°) in it. We have converted our object to JSON format using GSON (At this point everything is well). 
 When we send this JSON over to the back end, the back end uses jackson to convert the JSON back to the object. In this case where the JSON contains the degree symbol the back end throws an exception saying that it cannot handle the error.

I would really appreciate it if anybody could help me out with the issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can we see the relevant json, the relevant gson and jackson code, and the exact error please

Comment: related question with a workaround http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4901133/json-and-escaping-characters