# json_decode return "JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX", however JSON seems OK

Tags: php, json

What is wrong with this JSON string in PHP?

```
[{"Type":"Chasse|Loisirs","Productions":"Bois d\'Œuvre|Bois de chauffage","Essences principales > Feuillus":"Bouleaux|Hêtres|Merisiers|Peupliers"}]
```

I try online tools validators like [this one](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/), and JSON seems valid, but with PHP I still have an error:

```
$result = json_decode($json) 
// JSON_ERROR_SYNTAX
```

I try remove UTF-8 BOM, `stripslashes`, `htmlentities`... without success.

Why this JSON is malformed, and how to make it OK?

Comment: Nope its working. [Online Check](https://3v4l.org/BLFuW)

Comment: `\'` is not valid JSON.

Comment: Your JSON is valid. Try jsonlint.com

Comment: JSON is valid but the `JSON Standard` detect you have an invalid character.

Comment: Yes but why json_decode return error ? it makes me crazy...

Comment: @Bertrand Because the JSON is invalid? Once again, `\'` is *not* valid JSON.

Comment: @aldrin27: No, it isn't, and jsonlint.com helpfully says so. :-)

Comment: @FrayneKonok: The JSON is **not** valid. Your check is only working because the JSON is inside a PHP string quoted with `'`, so the `\'` is handled by PHP and just a `'` ends up in the JSON. But JSON with an actual `\'` sequence in a string is *not* valid.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks for valuable information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The JSON is not valid because you do NOT need to escape `'` character. Check for example this question [How to escape special characters in building a JSON string?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19176131/2111430)

The [JSON RFC 7159](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159) has this section

```
  char = unescaped /
      escape (
          %x22 /          ; "    quotation mark  U+0022
          %x5C /          ; \    reverse solidus U+005C
          %x2F /          ; /    solidus         U+002F
          %x62 /          ; b    backspace       U+0008
          %x66 /          ; f    form feed       U+000C
          %x6E /          ; n    line feed       U+000A
          %x72 /          ; r    carriage return U+000D
          %x74 /          ; t    tab             U+0009
          %x75 4HEXDIG )  ; uXXXX                U+XXXX
```

The `'` is not in the list.

I made a lot of changes with the question related with escaping Unicode characters. Formally this is not required. Check for example this question [JSON and escaping characters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4908960/2111430)

Comment: Finally done with editing. Hope now the answer is correct. Please let me know if you see any issues.

Answer (score 0):

Victor Smirnov already gave a good answer above, however I want to explain how you can debug such an error:

If you enter your JSON in http://jsonlint.com/ it will show the following:

```
Error: Parse error on line 3:
...s",  "Productions": "Bois d\'Œuvre|Bois 
----------------------^
Expecting 'STRING', 'NUMBER', 'NULL', 'TRUE', 'FALSE', '{', '[', got 'undefined'
```

This does not immediately show you what is wrong exactly, but it does show you that something is wrong with the string

```
"Bois d\'Œuvre|Bois de chauffage"
```

By replacing or removing the string character by character, you can find out that the single quote should not be escaped.

So it should be:

```
"Bois d'Œuvre|Bois de chauffage"
```