# Google App Engine Python JSON Encoding To UTF-8

Tags: python, utf-8

I am having a hard time converting Cyrillic symbols stored in Unicode to UTF-8 using Python's json library. 
The input JSON string:

```
data = '{"name": "\\u0431\\u0433"}'
```

The encoded result I am getting from `json.dumps(data)` and `json.dumps(data).encode('utf8')` is identical to the input, no conversion takes place.

Even more oddly, `json.dumps(data, ensure_ascii=False).encode('utf8')` returns a hexadecimal result: 
`'{"name": "\xd0\xb1\xd0\xb3"}'`
Does anyone have idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that you are doing wrong is trying to serialise `data`, which is already serialised as `JSON`.  The unicode escapes - `'\\uxxxx'` - are legitimate equivalent representations of cyrillic characters.

```
>>> data = '{"name": "\\u0431\\u0433"}'    # already json-serialised                                                                                          
>>> obj = json.loads(data)                 # deserialise to a python object
>>> obj                                                                                                                              
{u'name': u'\u0431\u0433'}                                                                                                           

>>> print obj['name']  # printing the string displays as cyrillic
бг
```

Escaping unicode characters is permitted by the standard ([see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4908960/5320906)).  Other json parsers will process escaped characters correctly.

For example, in the Firefox console:

```
data = '{"name": "\\u0431\\u0433"}'
"{"name": "\u0431\u0433"}"
obj = JSON.parse(data)
Object { name: "бг" }
```